# Is there a height derived version of the CSS aspect ratio hackery?

Tags: css

I know about the one where the width is set and you use top/bottom padding to maintain a certain aspect ratio like so

```js
var container = document.querySelector("#container");
var a = 0;
(function(){
  container.style.width = (100 + 25 * Math.cos(a)) + "px";
  container.style.height = (100 + 25 * Math.sin(a)) + "px";
  a += 0.01;
  setTimeout(arguments.callee, 4);
})();
```

```css
#container {
  border:1px solid black;
}

#aspect_box {
  width:100%;
  padding-top:100%;
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  position:relative;
}

#aspect_box:after {
  content:"1:1";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"> <div id="aspect_box"></div> </div>
```

But in my case, I need the height to be set and width to be variable. I don't even understand the logic behind top/bottom margin keeping the aspect ratio but using left/right margin doesn't work the same way.

Anyway, is there CSS for keeping aspect ratio with the height fixed to the container?

Comment: After lots of looking, I found this: https://codeburst.io/keeping-aspect-ratio-with-html-and-no-padding-tricks-40705656808b there they use a single cell grid to size a single element but the method can also be used to manage the dimensions of the element containing the grid and other elements within the grid with the min-content template flag used on the cell containing the SVG. Lots of experimental implementation in there though, works in chrome, limited use in FF and broken everywhere else.